# How to make a BIT stronger negation?

Tags: expressions, sentence-choice

In my view, we can use the word "**NO**" to substitute "**NOT**" to express a bit stronger negation. For example, "**He is no singer.**" put a bit emphasis on negative, compared with "**He is not a singer.**"

But how about this sentence: **He has not come to New York**? Can we put "**He has no come to New York**" in order to make a *bit* stronger negation? If not, how can we put?

Are there any other ways that can also be suggested?

My bounty is mainly for the question: "**I'd like to know if "He has not come to New York whatsoever." would make a bit stronger negation than "He has not come to New York."?**"

Comment: Did you invent the “rule”?

Comment: @dan I can't help but wonder if it's a typo in your comment. Did you mean to say "I am **not** trying to invent a rule"?

Comment: @dan Since you can't edit a comment past the initial 5 minutes after its posting, if you want to have it corrected, you can flag it and ask the moderators to fix it for you. I made that suggestion with a flag earlier today but was declined. I guess they didn't see the typo. As the author of that comment, your flag should be heeded.

Comment: @StephieI am not trying to invent a rule, but I'd like to know if there is a way to express a bit stronger negation.

Comment: @EddieKal, I just deleted that one and added a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He has not come to New York whatsoever.

is stronger than

> He has not come to New York.

However, I would say that it is *much* stronger rather than *a bit* stronger.

I think a good in between would be

> He still has not come to New York.

Answer (score 7):

No.

One of the senses of "no" is its use as a determiner. In this use it is "no + noun" meaning "not any"  (There is no water) or "not a" (He is no singer).

This latter use has the "quite/very" sense, and can imply "He is very much not a singer". This is the sense you refer to.

On the other hand, "not" is a particle, that is used to form the negation of verbs  "He 'has not come'" is the negation of  "He has come".  This can be considered as a special type of adverb.  The word "no" cannot substitute for "not" in this case.

The expression "He has no come to New York" is not grammatically correct for this reason.

Instead just use an adverb like "never":

> He has never come to New York.
>   He has not come close to New York
>   He has not come to New York since he was born.

Comment: Are there any suggestions?

Comment: @dan *He is no* ***newcomer*** *to New York.* That turns the verb after *no* into a noun, making it acceptable. (However, the meaning is now a bit different. But so long as you use a noun that fits *no X to New York* you are fine.) Or, use a different intensifier. *He has* ***certainly*** *not come to New York.*

Comment: How about "He has not come to New York whatsoever."?

Comment: @dan Your sentence might be better as "He **has not been** to New York whatsoever."

Comment: @peter  You could also word the sentence like, "He **never came** to New York [whatsoever]," instead of "**has not been**" assuming that the original intent of the statement is referring to the subject not arriving to New York (not alluding to whether the subject has been to New York prior) versus had never gone to New York before (as implied by "has not been to").

Answer (score 3):

As James K said in his answer, in order to use the "no + something" pattern, you need a noun that follows **no**. It is a noun phrase with **no** being the determiner. So your proposed sentence doesn't work. But there are alternatives that do.

In addition to what has been said in the two existing good answers, you can also say this

> He has been **nowhere near** New York

This sentence definitely implies a strong sense of negation, stating that "he" has never been to New York.

The adverb "whatsoever" means *at all* and can oftentimes substitute for "at all".

> He had no respect for you at all.
>
> He had no respect for you whatsoever.

So of course appending "whatsoever" to a sentence makes for a stronger negation, not just a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is incorrect. *No* cannot be associated with a verb (**no come* is improper) - *not* is required in this case.

There's no real way to emphasize your second sentence in proper English without the use of an adjective:

> He has **absolutely/definitely/...** not come to New York

If you used *no*, you'd have to prefix it to *New York*, not *come* - making for a very awkward and unnatural sentence, implying that said person came *somewhere*, but it wasn't New York:

> *He has come to **no** New York.

You might also hear some speakers use the following double negative, which does a better job serving as an emphasis of the original meaning, but I strongly discourage you from using it - it's not proper English and it's bound to make you sound uneducated:

> *He has **not** come to **no** New York.